# Topic links broken in reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, broken-link, reputation-tab

I received +5 reputation on topic "Undefined behavior" in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). It turns out that the entire topic was cited. However in both Achievements dropdown and [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala?tab=reputation) the link leads to example 364 of [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) instead of topic 364 of [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

On my reputation tab that shows up as

> +5      24 mins ago     topic cited     [Undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/364) in [Extra integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39319841) in the output.

I guess the former link should have been to [`https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/t/364`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364) instead of [`https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/364`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/364).

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.